# Adding username to computer description

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, active-directory

Is there a way to add the user name to all computer descriptions in AD? Something like a powershell script?

Comment: [my answer][1] for this incorporates the "microsoft scripting guy" method


  [1]: http://serverfault.com/questions/223471/how-can-i-run-a-process-as-nt-authority-networkservice/318130#318130

Comment: [my answer][1] for this incorporates the "microsoft scripting guy":



  [1]: http://serverfault.com/questions/223471/how-can-i-run-a-process-as-nt-authority-networkservice/318130#318130

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use my answer [here](https://serverfault.com/a/276313/4487) and modify it a bit.